# Data not displaying out despite auto-selecting gridview row

Tags: c#, asp.net, gridview

I'm trying to let the gridview auto-select the first row of data upon page load. However, in the gridview, it shows that the first row is being highlighted

[image]

but no data is being displayed in my textbox. The data only appears when i click the select button in my gridview again.

This is how i added the auto-select gridview row in my page load

```
protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {          
        if (!IsPostBack)
            {
                 gvnric.SelectedIndex = 0;
            }
        }
```

This is how i get my data from my gridview to my textbox

```
protected void gvnric_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        Session["nric"] = gvnric.SelectedRow.Cells[1].Text;


        SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection(ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["ConnectionString"].ConnectionString);
        con.Open();
        SqlCommand cm = new SqlCommand("Select fullname, contact, address, email From MemberAccount Where nric = '" + Session["nric"] + "'", con);
        SqlDataReader dr;
        dr = cm.ExecuteReader();
        if (dr.Read())
        {
            txtFullName.Text = dr["fullname"].ToString();
            txtAddress.Text = dr["contact"].ToString();
            txtContact.Text = dr["address"].ToString();
            txtEmail.Text = dr["email"].ToString();
        }
        con.Close();

        Image1.Attributes["src"] = "MemberNricCard.aspx?";
        Image1.Attributes["height"] = "200";
        Image1.Attributes["width"] = "200";
    }
```

But what could possibly caused the data not to be displayed when the first row already being selected upon page load.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can just call your gridview code in the page load

```
    protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        if (!IsPostBack)
            {

                gvnric.SelectedIndex = 0;
                gvnric_SelectedIndexChanged(this, EventArgs.Empty);
            }
        }
```

Answer (score 0):

I would Re Factor the code as below :

**PageLoad**

```
if (!IsPostBack)
{
     gvnric.SelectedIndex = 0;
     LoadFormFields();
}
```

**gvnric_SelectedIndexChanged**

```
protected void gvnric_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    LoadFormFields();
}
```

and create `LoadFormFields` with what you have in `gvnric_SelectedIndexChanged`